# Toggle alternative keyboard behaviour in Gnumeric

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, gnumeric

When using Gnumeric, one can usually navigate between cells using the keyboard arrows and change the content of a cell just by typing the wanted content.

However, I sometimes find myself in a situation where I have to double-click a cell to be able to modify it, and the arrows won’t move the cursor.  Most of the control-key shortcuts work, but I also observed a few other strange issues I am not able to recall.

Usually I restart Gnumeric to get the original behaviour back.

However I am suspecting this different behaviour may just be triggered by some toggle shortcut, since I observed it with different Gnumeric and OS versions.

Does Gnumeric have such a shortcut or a menu entry to switch between keyboard & cells behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same today on Gnumeric 1.12.17 (FR) on Windows.

(Even if more recent versions of Gnumeric exist, as they don't distribute Windows versions, my usual provider - Clubic - is still distributing this old version)

I had the exact same problem on a new tab I had created. All other tabs were working well (edit and arrows).

I closed Gnumeric and restarted it and reopened file and all is now OK on all tabs, it fixed the problem.